# What causes drag in a fluid?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, drag, viscosity

What causes resistance of an object to motion within a fluid like water?  Please explain to me the molecular dynamics of the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an object moves in a fluid, the fluid molecules just around it get entrained along with it due to friction. In turn, this layer of fluid entrains the next layer at a lower velocity, and so on.  This is due to the fact that individual molecules switch layer and thus "diffuse" the momentum (a molecule coming from a fast layer to a slower transfers some momentum to it, and vice-versa). In liquids, molecular interactions are added on top of that.

The total frictional energy dissipated by this friction corresponds to the total energy needed to achieve the displacement of the object, and the ratio of the force to the velocity attained is called the drag.

Comment: What do you mean "due to friction", I specified 'molecular dynamics', so what is actually happening, for instance, are the water molecules temporarily bonding to the surfaces of the object?

Comment: Not necessarily, e.g. gases have a nonzero viscosity. This is due to the fact that individual molecules switch layer and thus "diffuse" the momentum (a molecule coming from a fast layer to a slower transfers some momentum to it, and vice-versa). In liquids, molecular interactions are added on top of that.

Answer (score 1):

There can be drag arising from individual layers in the fluid moving in different relative velocities. There are other types of drag due to the motion of a fluid but I think this is what you are asking for.

Comment: See my comment to Joce.